# C# Winforms control for mapping between two List<string>

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have been searching Google for a WinForms C# compatible control that allows me to link two `List<string>` together.

I created a mock-up of what I'm after using Excel.

[image]

The idea is to allow the person using my program to link the two `List<string>` together using a click, drag and drop method.

I want the person using the control to be able to click and hold from one black dot to another to form a link (displayed as a line). If the mouse button is released before making a link then no link should be made.

To remove a link, hovering the cursor over a line should highlight it (only one should be highlighted). Clicking when a line is highlighted should remove the link.

Does anybody know a solution to this very specific problem?

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to roll your own.

Comment: So you want users to be able to click on an item in `List A` and then click on the category that item belongs to in `List B` and you want the control to draw a line between the two? You'll definitely have to make your own custom control, but it shouldn't be too hard to capture the mouse location on the first and second click then [draw a line](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+draw+a+line&oq=C%23+draw+a+line&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j0l4.2031j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @sab669 Very nearly. I want the person using the control to be able to click and hold from one black dot to another to form a link (displayed as a line). If the mouse button is released before making a link then no link should be made. Hovering over a line should highlight one line, and clicking when a line is highlighted should remove the link.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins More or less the same thing. Handle the mouse down, validate the coordinates, draw a dot. Handle the mouse up, validate the coordinates again, draw a second dot. Then draw a line between the two coordinates. Then store references to those 3 somewhere so you can delete them if the user "de-links" a pair.

Comment: Looks like a many-to-many relations. You can set such a relationship in a `DataSet`.

Comment: This seems like a nice chalange to write one, but I don't think you'll find anything ready made.

Comment: could you give us maybe an update? I was thinking to write something like that in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any mainstream control like this. In .NET or any program I've seen so far.

You could probably replicate something like this with various datagrid controls using an m-n relationship between two tables.

Other than that I'd say this looks like the text book definition of a custom control...